# Nested for loop with if statement in Jinja fails to work

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPiNC.png)enter code here`

```html
<div class="container">
    {% for bookmark_title in bookmarks_titles %}
      <div class="container-head">
          <h2>{{ bookmark_title.title }}</h2>
          <span>{{bookmark_title.description}}</span>
      </div>
      {% for bookmark in bookmarks %}
          {% if bookmark.tag == bookmark_title.title %}
            <div class="container-body">
            <a href="{{ bookmark.url }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{bookmark.favicon}}" alt="icon" /> {{ bookmark["title"]}}</a>
            </div>
          {% endif %} 
      {% endfor %}  
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

When I run the HTML the first for loop works as expected however, the second nested for loop and if statement only runs after the parent for loop ends.
But I want to return the "Bookmark" saved under each Bookmark_title.title.

As you can see in the attached image for nested for loop works only after the parent for loop ends.

Any suggestion, please.

Comment: can you show us the `bookmarks_titles` and `bookmarks` list structure

Comment: @FareedKhan I used SQLAlchemy to create a different sheet in the database.
Link to the screenshot of the database.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZKHqcZpOTaZzxwHTjKttpPXP4SJzDYzQ?usp=sharing

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you provided, actually it is rendering `a tag` for `entertainment` title only. I cannot recommend you much but these two `noob` solutions.
1) clear `cache` of website by pressing `Ctrl + F5` to check if it works.
2) You can run both the loops based on rows count using `range` function and see if it is executing correctly.

Comment: Since you are making string comparisons: are you sure there's no extra space in the `title` and/or `tag` fields? For debugging you can put an `{% else %}` branch and print the values of the fields.

Comment: @FareedKhan It is still the same tried both already.

Comment: @Dauros Both the `title` and `tag` are dynamically created. Once the user provide the `title` I passed that into the drop-down selectors in the form as a `tag`. So both the `title` string and the `tag` string must be the same. Just to double check as you mentioned will try pass the {% else %} and see if it helps.

Comment: `@FareedKhan` & `@Dauros` OMG. Thank you so much. You guys have opened my eyes. `{% else %}` actually helped me to find the issue. In the process of `filtering all the bookmarks` before passing it to the HTML page. Instead of appending I was replacing so `only the bookmarks`, I filtered using the `last title tag` in this case `Entertainment` only passed into the HTML page which caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of `filtering all the bookmarks` before passing them to the HTML page. `Instead of appending` the filtered data from the database.db I was `replacing with the new results` so `only the bookmarks`, I `filtered` using the `last title` tag in this case `Entertainment` only `passed` into the `HTML page` which caused the `issue`.

To fix it I filtered all the bookmarks from the database.db since the 'Bookmarks' sheet only has the bookmarks, so I don't need to filter by tag.)

```
# Previously
for tag in tags:
    bookmarks = db.session.query(Bookmarks).filter_by(tag=tag)
```

## Fix

```
bookmarks = db.session.query(Bookmarks).all()
```